# jQuery .on() tr click event using .not() on tr checkbox click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, click, live

So my title may be confusing, but it has the right details. I have a table with clickable rows. When clicking the row, the row highlights. The table also has a checkbox column. **Clicking the checkbox should NOT highlight or remove highlight from the row.** How can I properly use .not() or :not in the .on('click', 'tr', function(){ ... }) ? http://jsfiddle.net/vmu0p2oe/

```
$('table').on('click', 'tr', function () {
                if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
                    $(this).removeClass('selected');
                    //$(this).find(":checkbox").prop("checked", false);
                }
                else {
                    $('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
                    $(this).addClass('selected');
                    //$(this).find(":checkbox").prop("checked", true);
                }

            });
```

Comment: That beautiful moment when you find *exactly* the problem you were trying to solve.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add this to the beginning of the handler:

```
if($(e.target).is('input[type=checkbox]')) {
    return;
}
```

This will stop the handler from running if the element clicked is a checkbox.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vmu0p2oe/1/

Answer (score 1):

Add a handler for the checkbox that uses `stopPropagation()` to prevent the click from bubbling out to the `tr`:

```
$('table').on('click', ':checkbox', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vmu0p2oe/2/)

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
$('table').on('click', 'tr', function (e) {
  var el = e.target;
  if ( el.type !== "checkbox"){
    if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
         $(this).removeClass('selected');
         //$(this).find(":checkbox").prop("checked", false);
    } else {
         $('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
         $(this).addClass('selected');
         //$(this).find(":checkbox").prop("checked", true);
    }
  }
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vmu0p2oe/3/)